# Implementing AVL Binary search tree with java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm supposed to implement a BST as a homework and decipher a "hidden message". I'm provided DataElement.java to use for the hidden message, but I'm unsure of how it works. It looks like the BSTTest file is derived from:

```
public class DataElement<T> implements Comparable<DataElement<T>> {
    private T value;
    private Integer weight;

    public DataElement(T t, int i) {
        this.value = t;
        this.weight = new Integer(i);

@Override
    public int compareTo(DataElement<T> o) {
        return this.weight.compareTo(o.weight);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

and with that, I'm given the test class. But I'm unsure of how the weight is interpreted, if thats the right wording. For instance:

```
public class BSTTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BinarySearchTree<DataElement<String>> root = new BinarySearchTree<DataElement<String>>(
        new DataElement<String>("u", 1782168893));
        root = root.insert(new DataElement<String>("A", -2138157432));
        root = root.insert(new DataElement<String>("e", 1219590329));
        root = root.insert(new DataElement<String>("z", -1205207264));
        root = root.insert(new DataElement<String>("e", 1147267944));
        root = root.insert(new DataElement<String>("A", 1534456190));
        root = root.insert(new DataElement<String>(" ", 963753082));
        root = root.insert(new DataElement<String>("t", -343169896));
        root = root.insert(new DataElement<String>("h", -719426805));
```

and so on... So what is the significance of the large +- numbers in the parameter?

Sorry if I'm not java articulate but I'm just looking for a place to start. I can't implement a tree if I'm unsure of how it works. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how a binary search works? ? ? Have you tired google?

Comment: @YaWang yes but a sufficient answer in text (and not code) is lacking. Maybe you can point me in the direction I should be looking if I missed it? More specific is what the weight signifies as a parameter.

Comment: The term weights has nothing to do with AVL tree. You seem to not have fully read and understood your asignement. Find out what "weight" is related, too.